# Is it possible to find 4 distinct functional dependencies in this table?

Tags: database, dependencies

My professor gave a task to find 4 distinct functional dependencies in the following table:

**Company**(Company_Name, Street_Address, City, Zip, State, CEO_Name)

"He also gave a note: Each company has a different (unique) address meaning (Street_Address, City, Zip, State) together form a key. Different companies may have the same name. Each company has exactly one CEO, and one person cannot be the CEO of more than one company. CEO names may not be unique (there maybe 2 CEOs with the same name). To count 4 functional dependencies in a table with attributes (A, B, C, D): If A -> B then obviously A, C -> B as well. This should not count as 2 separate dependencies. On the other hand, A -> B and A -> C should be counted as 2 distinct functional dependencies."

But in my opinion, there are no 4 functional dependencies.

1. CEO, Company Name -> (Street_address, city, zip, state)
2. zip -> state

but since two companies can have the same name there should be also a primary key like "Company_Number". But creating knew tables is not the task...

Answer (score 1):

Functional dependencies answer the question, "Give a single value for X, do we know one and only one value for Y?" Eitehr X or Y may be sets of attributes, not just a single attribute. Keep this in mind when you're reading through this answer.

> Each company has a different (unique) address meaning (Street_Address, City, Zip, State) together form a key.

By definition, that key means that

- Street_Address, City, Zip, State -> CEO_Name
- Street_Address, City, Zip, State -> Company_Name

That's all the possible FDs for the candidate key {Street_Address, City, Zip, State}. Two of four--halfway home.

You identified {CEO_Name, Company_name} as the left-hand side of a functional dependency. In this particular case, you also identify it as a candidate key.  Let's look at some made-up data.

```
Company_Name  CEO_Name    Street_Address  City      State  Zip
--
Wibble, Inc.  Mary Smith  123 E Main St   Anytown   PA     00001
Wibble, Inc.  Mary Smith  456 S Darn St   Sometown  WY     10000
```

That data describes two different companies that happen to have the same name, having two different CEOs who happen to have the same name.  This fits the description of the FDs, but clearly shows that {Company_Name, CEO_Name} is *not* a candidate key.  The faked data also clearly shows that {Company_Name, CEO_Name} can't be the left-hand side of a functional dependency. Given a single value for {Company_Name, CEO_Name}, we don't have one and only one value for any of the other attributes.

Having eliminated the attributes Company_Name and CEO_Name as possibilities for the left-hand side, the only way to "manufacture" two more functional dependencies is to find them *within* the candidate key {Street_Address, City, Zip, State}. Not because there's anything special about the candidate key, but because those are the only attributes left.

My *guess* is that your teacher expects you to say

- Zip -> City
- Zip -> State

In the USA (in the "real" world), "Zip -> City, State" doesn't hold. ZIP codes have to do with how carriers drive their routes and deliver mail; ZIP codes aren't concerned with geography. A few cities (and ZIP codes) straddle state borders. Quite a lot of ZIP codes straddle adjoining cities within a single state. As the USPS cuts their budget, I expect the number of such ZIP codes to increase.

But in academia, this real-world behavior is often ignored for pedagogical reasons. That's why I'll bet your teacher expects {Zip -> City, State}.

Comment: And ZIP -> State is not a transitive dependency? Because City -> State?? Or is it not a transitive dependency because there can be cities with the same name in different states??

Comment: Transitive dependencies are defined on non-prime attributes. You'd  have to argue that *"(Street_Address, City, Zip, State) together form a key"* means they form a superkey, not a candidate key. A candidate key is an irreducible superkey; if `ZIP -> City, State`, you have a reducible superkey, and City and State aren't really prime attributes.